# How to match case-sensitive username and password

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to match user name and password using linq in C# using sql server

```
    //verify the user.
    var UserDetails = 
    (from user in con.ios_Users
    where (user.LOGIN == LogReq.userName && user.PASSWORD == LogReq.password && user.ACTIVE != 0)

    select new
    {
        user.ID,
        user.TYPEDESCR,
        user.USERNAME
    }).ToList();
```

In above code it returns data user data if i am passing username - demo and password - demo123 but in database user name is  - DeMo and password is DeMo123 
How to make this linq query case sensitive :(

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try using the Equals method. `user.PASSWORD.Equals(LogReq.password)`

Comment: obligatory, fwiw, don't store passwords in clear text in a database - or anywhere really

Comment: @Dumisani : tried your code it returns data it not case sensitive :(

Comment: It is better not to store the actual password, but a hash of it. Then at least that will be case sensitive

Comment: please please please: **stop now**; this is a **serious** security problem, not a trivial one, and you are being actively harmful to your users just by having this data; you **must not** store passwords for the purposes of authentication - that *just isn't how you do auth*; if this is a student project (we see those occasionally), please take the opportunity to tell your teacher/lecturer that they're very wrong (send them to me, if you like; I'm fine with it!); if this is "real" stuff, **STOOOOOPP**; this is VERY VERY WRONG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a database collation issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver15

> Collations in SQL Server provide sorting rules, case, and accent sensitivity properties for your data. Collations that are used with character data types, such as char and varchar, dictate the code page and corresponding characters that can be represented for that data type.

The above is for MsSql but it applies for most mainstream databases.

If you are using linqToSql, then the linq is turned to a query and executed in the database, so the actual comparison occurs on the SQL side.

So you need to fix collation on your table.

Answer (score 0):

String comparison is case sensitive by default in C# (unless you use specific string comparison mechanisms).

Seeing how you say that:

> but in database user name is

Assuming you are using some sort of LinQ to SQL, most likely the culprit is the way in which your column is set up. Some DB engines, by default, match strings in a case insensitive manner, which seems to be the case here as well.

Answer (score -1):

You should use [String.Equals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=netframework-4.8)

```
//verify the user.
var UserDetails = 
(from user in con.ios_Users
where (string.Equals(user.LOGIN, LogReq.userName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && string.Equals(user.PASSWORD, LogReq.password , StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && user.ACTIVE != 0)

select new
{
    user.ID,
    user.TYPEDESCR,
    user.USERNAME
}).ToList();
```

Comment: This is exactly what the OP does not want, no?

Comment: it gives error :( **Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method 'Boolean Equals(System.String, System.String, System.StringComparison)**

Comment: I've just updated my answer, please take a look @npinti

Comment: You're still ignoring the Case, which is not what the OP wants

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Anuradha Dawkore